# Battery Laptop Charging very slow. Battery Diagnostics; charge rate 10.000mw

Tags: laptop, battery, asus-laptop, charging

I have a new laptop. But It takes 4 hours till the battery is full.

I get 95% battery health status. My adapter is 45W (19V at 2.3A).

I get this rates when charging:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nycz.png)

Is this normal?

Comment: Depending on the processor and other components 45W might be on the low side to charge it when in use, especially if the laptop is working hard. More details are needed.

Comment: The original adapter is; 45W.

Comment: Charge rate is 10.000mw for 12V. This seems to be low?

Comment: 10,000 mW = 10 Watts, which is a respectable charging current.  And, you're three monthis into your battery warranty, since your battery has a 1 year warranty https://www.asus.com/in/About_ASUS/Warranty/ . If you have 95% capacity at 75% of your warranty left, that's decent.

Comment: 12V and 10W is charging current of 0.8A. The charger indicates 2.3A max output at 19V?

Comment: Overcharging Lithium based batteries leads to fires, which could be a Bad Thing. It will take as much as it takes,

Comment: It takes 5 hours to full charge the battery. This is very slow. It seems like that the charge current of original adapter is low.. Any other ideas?

Comment: 2 months ago, it was like 2 hours

Comment: Yep. That's why your lappie has a 2 yr warranty, but the battery only has a one year warranty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the full charge on a brand-new battery of 40,076 mWH is
5 % less than the design capacity of 42,103 mWH,
I would return it to the vendor for replacement.

A brand-new battery should be at the design capacity, period.

Comment: It's 3 months old.

Comment: Then it is not new, Your battery has a 1 year warranty, so you're 25% through the warranty per https://www.asus.com/in/About_ASUS/Warranty/